# How to number a group of equations in html/Mathjax

Tags: html, mathjax, equation-number

I am using MathJax on my website. When I number a single equation, it turns out all right. However, for a group of equations, it doesn't work. I have to modify the code like below and only then the Eq number appears.

```
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A &= B + C \\
&= D
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}\label{equation-example}
$$
```

I know that $$ is from Tex and shouldn't be encouraged. This code looks like a bad practice anyway. What is the proper way of handling this in LateX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> What is the proper way of handling this in LaTeX?

Introductory remark: Purely Mathjax-focused questions are off-topic for this site. But since you specifically ask how to handle the situation as if it were a LaTeX document, the query is indeed ok for TeX.SE. :-)

I'd say a "proper" way is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document clas
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'aligned' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{equation-example}
\begin{aligned}  
A &= B + C \\
  &= D
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

An issue that you didn't address in your query is: *Where*, i.e., on which row of the multirow expression, should the equation number be placed?

- When one writes `\begin{aligned}`, the default kicks in, which is for the equation number to be placed *vertically centered* on the group of expressions. For the case at hand, this means placing the equation number between the two rows, since both rows are equally tall.
- If, on the other hand, you want the equation number to be placed either on the *top* or *bottom* row of the multi-row expression, you should write `\begin{aligned}[t]` or `\begin{aligned}[b]`, respectively.

Comment: Makes sense. It turns out that the equation number is displayed correctly in this case but when I refer to this number, the webpage displays it as Eq (???). However, for a single equation or my original $$ solution, this problem does not arise. Any clue?

Comment: @QMC - A sentence such as `A cross-reference to equation \textup{(\ref{equation-example})}.`, when added to the code shown above, definitely generates the expected output under LaTeX. I know very little about Mathjax, though, and I'm afraid I can't help you out on how to generate cross-references on your website.

Comment: No worries. It has already been a great help. Which SE forum can I ask this question about the reference?

Comment: @QMC - I would try [Superuser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/). Be sure to stress that you're looking for a Mathjax-based solution, *not* a LaTeX-based solution.